# Weird issue occurs when using the Alacritty terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, zsh, terminal-emulator

I have tried asking this on Alacritty's GitHub issues tab and just got this:

```
This is an issue with your system, likely related to _TERM_ or your _PS1_.
```

The issue is as follows: *SOMETIMES*, when a program exits without a newline as the last character added to `stdout`, the terminal bugs out and does not go to the start of the next line. Here are some examples:

```
finxx > alacritty --version
alacritty 0.10.1 (2844606d)
                           %
finxx >
```

```
finxx > printf "asd\nasd\nasd\n"
asd
   asd
      asd
         %
finxx >
```

```
finxx > echo $TERM
alacritty
         %
finxx >
```

```
finxx > echo $PS1
%F{red}%@%f %F{yellow}%m%f %F{#FFFF00}%n%f %F{green}%~%f %F{cyan}%?%f >
                                                                        %
finxx >
```

Yes, my `$PS1` is different from the prompt in the examples. That is because I am writing this post on another computer, and typing that out would be a pain.
This issue has persisted through TWO DIFFERENT COMPUTERS. The only solution is to close the terminal emulator and reopen it. `. ~/.zshrc` does nothing as well. This is an issue on my new Arch Linux install where `alacritty` is the last thing in my `~./xinitrc`. This also affects `bash`, but I don't use bash as my main shell.

Comment: Can be reproduced with `stty -onlcr`. Something's messing up the tty line discipline settings. Run `stty sane` or here specificallly `stty onlcr`

Comment: stty sane works. Do you have any idea why this only happens with alacritty?